how to transfer minter's all authority from wallet to contract program?
Normally we create minter / token on program, thereafter, the program owns the mint authority, for example:
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(symbol: String, decimals: u8)]
pub struct AddToken<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint = admin.key() == ADMIN_ACCOUNT,
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    // The PDA is both the address of the mint account and the mint authority
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        seeds = [symbol.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        mint::decimals = decimals,
        mint::authority = mapping_token_mint,
    )]
    pub mapping_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
            
    // ... 
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>, 
}


What if there is a minter created by cli and it mint authority is a wallet?
How can I transfer all authority to contract program ?  Are Update Authority, Mint Authority the complete  authority list to tranfer to program?
I want the minter is fully transfer to program without any right remain in wallet account.
Can anybody show my how to or provide some source link?
//Edit1:
@Jimii provide a JS approach. But later on, I found I need rust contract method to archive this, because I need to register the minter and check if the supply is zero.
Thanks

If you created a token using the CLI, you can assign a PDA/new address as the mint account's authority (freeze and mint).
In Typescript using the @solana/spl-token package
// transfer mint and freeze authorities
async function TransferAuth() {
    let mint = new PublicKey("");

    const newAuthority = new PublicKey("");

    // hand over freeze authority
    let freezeAuthIx = createSetAuthorityInstruction(
        mint,
        signer.publicKey,
        AuthorityType.FreezeAccount,
        newAuthority
    );

    // hand over mint authority
    let mintAuthIx = createSetAuthorityInstruction(
        mint,
        signer.publicKey,
        AuthorityType.MintTokens,
        newAuthority
    );

    const tx = await new Transaction().add(freezeAuthIx).add(mintAuthIx);
    let txHash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(conn, tx, [signer]);
    console.log(txHash);
}

You can also update the metadata UpdateAuthority using Metaplex UMI and mpl-token-metadata package
    await updateV1(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        data: { ...onChainMetadata, name: newName },
        primarySaleHappened: true,
        newUpdateAuthority: publicKey(newAuthority.toBase58()),
        isMutable: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update#new-update-authority

wow, great examples, I will try it soon.
